# AutoCad with Asus Nexus 7

Tags: android, tablet, cad

Hey i just got a tablet for christmas and i do 3dModelling in college using Autodesk 3dsMax.  I was just wondering is it possible to use the tablet with CAD ?

Comment: This should be asked on either superuser or android.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do not ask these type of questions here. Use as pointed out by AC - superuser or android.stackexchange.

Secondly, there's an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autodesk.autocadws) that exists. You should've searched the play store.